# BelongsToMany relationship sync causes Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables, `articles`, `categories`, and a pivot table `article_category`.
There can be many categories. An article can have multiple categories. A category can belong to multiple articles.

The [`belongsToMany::sync`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_sync) method causes the `Integrity constraint violation` error when attempting to add a `Category` to an `Article`. It works when trying to remove the `Category` from the `Article`.

<kbd>Article.php</kbd>

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Enums\ArticleType;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body',
        'user_id',
        'status',
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function setCategories($categories)
    {
        $this->categories()->sync($categories);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function isPublished()
    {
        return $this->status == ArticleType::PUBLISHED;
    }

    public function isDraft()
    {
        return $this->status == ArticleType::DRAFT;
    }
}
```

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`y2kro_main`.`article_category`, CONSTRAINT `article_category_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

[image]

The `setCategories` method is called from a Livewire component:

<kbd>Articles/Edit.php</kbd>

```php
public function publish()
{
    $this->authorize('update', $this->article);

    $this->validate();

    $this->article->status = ArticleType::PUBLISHED;
    $this->article->save();

    $this->article->setCategories($this->selectedCategories);

    return $this->flash('success', __('Article published successfully.'), ['background' => '#283046'], route('articles.show', $this->article));
}
```

`$this->selectedCategories` is an `Array` of IDs referencing categories in the `categories` table.

### Few interesting facts I've noticed:

The code works as expected, without giving the `Integrity constraint violation` on a `MariaDB` server.

The server it throws the error on is a `MySQL Community Server v5.7`.

Manually running the SQL Query from the error will not give an error (on the `MySQL Community Server v5.7` server).
[image]

Setting the `article_id` and `category_id` rows on the pivot table to `nullable` did not work.

### Additional Information

- IDs of both, `articles` and `categories` tables are Snowflakes.
- PHP 8.1
- Laravel 9

---

#### Adding additional information as per [xenooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20283630/xenooooo)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620430/belongstomany-relationship-sync-causes-integrity-constraint-violation?noredirect=1#comment131717071_74620430):

The contents of `$selectedCategories` in the `setCategories` method are:

```json
array:2 [▼ // app\Http\Livewire\Articles\Edit.php:63
  0 => "120847411458478080"
  1 => "120847442089480192"
]
```

The IDs are a reference of `Category1` and `Category2`:
[image]

The IDs come from multiple checkboxes on the front end:

```php
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input wire:model="selectedCategories" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="category_{{ $category->id }}" value="{{ $category->id }}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="category_{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</label>
        @error('selectedCategories.' . $category->id) <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    </div>
@endforeach
```

---

#### Update - found something interesting

Changing the `id` of the `Category` to auto-increment and removing the snowflake seems to have fixed this issue, though, this is not the ideal fix I'm looking for.

It is difficult to say why the `Integrity constraint violation` error might occur on a MySQL Community Server but not on a MariaDB. It seems that the issue may be related to how Laravel's Eloquent ORM is interacting with the database.

Comment: Can you add the content of `setCategories()` method

Comment: @xenooooo I've updated my question with the additional information.